# why use relative import failed when import code from source package in test package

Tags: python, testing, import

Here is the thing:

When you developing a project, and test the code, you don't want to copy the code to sys.path, I mean python site-packages.So you have to use relative import.

the structure is:

```
|- pymonitoringplusin

    |- ftp_ftplib.py

|- tests

    |- test_ftp.py
```

I want to import source code from develop path, not python site-packages.

Here is the code in test_ftp.py:

```
from ..pymonitoringplugins.ftp_ftplib.py import Ftp
```

But got error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Here is the source code:

https://github.com/crazy-canux/pymonitoringplugins

Comment: Sorry, the code is  :
from ..pymonitoringplugins.ftp_ftplib import Ftp

Comment: it is not working as package, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py